# CosmosDb LINQ query 'any' does not work but 'count() > 0' does?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I've got a Cosmos db linq query, and if I call 'Any()' on that query, it gives me the following exception:

> Compositions of aggregates and other expressions are not allowed.

But if I use 'Count() > 0' it does what I need. I thought 'any' was supported now? ([Link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/11503872-support-linq-any-or-where-for-child-object-collect))

Any thoughts on what the above exception means? Is it a bug in the CosmosDb client?

Answer (score 2):

`Any` is not supported by CosmosDb's Linq provider.

Please see [Supported LINQ operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-linq-to-sql#SupportedLinqOperators).

Comment: It kind of is, but only in where clauses apparently: 

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/11503872-support-linq-any-or-where-for-child-object-collect

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/899